# $T: V \rightarrow V$ a linear transformation such that $T^2 = I$ and $H_1= \{v \in V | T(v) = v\}\ $ and $H_2= \{v \in V|T(v) = -v\}\ $

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

Let V a vector space and $T: V \rightarrow V$ a linear transformation such that $T^2 = I$ and $H_1= \{v \in V | T(v) = v\}\ $ and $H_2= \{v \in V|T(v) = -v\}\ $ then $V = H_1 \bigoplus H_2$

I stuck in this problem please some help.

Comment: The statement is not necessarily true. Are there any additional assumptions about the ground field?

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Could you please provide a counter example? And then point out what is then wrong in my answer.

Comment: @surb Let $k$ be any field of characteristic $2$, let $V$ be any nontrivial  $k$-space and let $T$ be the identity. Then $H_1\cap H_2=V\ne 0$. The crucial step in your answer is: $v=-v\implies v=0$. This uses that the characteristic is $\ne 2$.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yes, I expected the "mistake" to be here. Thank you for this very interesting comment. I didn't knew (or forgot) fields and their characteristic before. So if I understood you well $^\mathbb{Z}/_{2\mathbb{Z}}$ would be such a field, because $[-1]_2 = [1]_2$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all it is clear that if $v \in H_1 \cap H_2$, then $v = T(v) = -v$ and so we must have $v = 0$. It follows that $H_1 \cap H_2 = 0$.

Now let $v \in V$, by definition of $T$, $T^2(v)= T(T(v))=v$ which implies that $T(v) \in H_1$, furthermore by linearity of $T$ holds $T(v-T(v)) = T(v)-T^2(v) = -(v-T(v))$ which shows that $v -T(v)\in H_2$. So $v = T(v)+(v-T(v)) \in H_1 + H_2$. Since it is obvious that $H_1 + H_2 \subset V$, the proof is done.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Just *assume* for the moment that you can write $v=h_1+h_2$ with $h_i\in H_i$. Can you express $Tv$ in terms of $h_1, h_2$? Can you then obtain $h_1,h_2$ from $v$ and $Tv$?